# Trim String in Java while preserve full word

Tags: java, string, substring, trim

I need to trim a String in java so that:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the laz dog.

becomes

> The quick brown...

In the example above, I'm trimming to 12 characters. If I just use substring I would get:

> The quick br...

I already have a method for doing this using substring, but I wanted to know what is the fastest (most efficient) way to do this because a page may have many trim operations.

The only way I can think off is to split the string on spaces and put it back together until its length passes the given length. Is there an other way? Perhaps a more efficient way in which I can use the same method to do a "soft" trim where I preserve the last word (as shown in the example above) and a hard trim which is pretty much a substring.

Thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Below is a method I use to trim long strings in my webapps.
The "soft" `boolean` as you put it, if set to `true` will preserve the last word.
This is the most concise way of doing it that I could come up with that uses a StringBuffer which is a lot more efficient than recreating a string which is immutable.

```
public static String trimString(String string, int length, boolean soft) {
    if(string == null || string.trim().isEmpty()){
        return string;
    }

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(string);
    int actualLength = length - 3;
    if(sb.length() > actualLength){
        // -3 because we add 3 dots at the end. Returned string length has to be length including the dots.
        if(!soft)
            return escapeHtml(sb.insert(actualLength, "...").substring(0, actualLength+3));
        else {
            int endIndex = sb.indexOf(" ",actualLength);
            return escapeHtml(sb.insert(endIndex,"...").substring(0, endIndex+3));
        }
    }
    return string;
}
```

**Update**

I've changed the code so that the `...` is appended in the StringBuffer, this is to prevent needless creations of `String` implicitly which is slow and wasteful.

**Note:** `escapeHtml` is a static import from apache commons:

`import static org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml;`

You can remove it and the code should work the same.

Comment: How `StringBuffer` helps performance here? There is no reason why `substring`, `indexOf` and `length` would be faster on `StringBuffer` than on `String`.

Comment: Let me clarify, the asker said it was tokenizing and then putting the string back together. Each time he appends a new token back on the string the entire string is destroyed and recreated. For long strings this operation is far more expensive than using a `StringBuffer`. Though I agree, the performance difference is probably negligible considering that the `StringBuffer` is created and when we return we are effectively creating a string at least 3 times (substring, append dots, escape [, trim]).

Comment: The problem is that in your code you are not appending anything to `StringBuffer`.

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely right the dots should be appended in the StringBuffer at the very least. I'll update my answer after testing the make sure there are no bugs.

Comment: @TranDinhThoai escapeHtml is a static import.
`import static org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml;`
You can remove it, it'll work the same. I have it there because I use it in a webapp and need to escape html entities.

Comment: @Ali It's still not worth to use `StringBuffer` here. Concatenating only two strings is unlikely to be faster than `+`. In both cases you are doing almost the same thing.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple, regex-based, 1-line solution:

```
str.replaceAll("(?<=.{12})\\b.*", "..."); // How easy was that!? :)
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=.{12})` is a *negative look behind*, which asserts that there are at least 12 characters to the left of the match, but it is a non-capturing (ie zero-width) match
- `\b.*` matches the first word boundary (after at least 12 characters - above) to the end

This is replaced with "..."

Here's a test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
    String trimmed = input.replaceAll("(?<=.{12})\\b.*", "...");
    System.out.println(trimmed);
}
```

Output:

```
The quick brown...
```

---

If performance is an issue, pre-compile the regex for an approximately 5x speed up (YMMV) by compiling it once:

```
static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=.{12})\\b.*");
```

and reusing it:

```
String trimmed = pattern.matcher(input).replaceAll("...");
```

Comment: Can you explain the regex? I like the solution, though I'll have to see how it stacks up speed wise to Ali's answer below.

Comment: @AMZFR don't use regex if you worry about speed. It's going to be much slower than `indexOf` + `substring` (10-100 times slower).

Comment: Thanks @Banthar, I was leaning against simply because I like knowing whats going on in the code, still the regex solution is quite elegant.

Comment: A nice answer. Simpler solution for when performance is not a prime factor

Comment: @SaifAsif I added a faster version if performance is required, although the original version would execute in only a few microseconds, so unless you needed this to run really really quickly, I’d favour the one-liner over statically compiling the regex.

Comment: Yes I saw, I bench-marked it and found a pass through of 33ms per token, which to be honest is pretty good enough for my use-case !

Answer (score 5):

Please try following code:

```
private String trim(String src, int size) {
    if (src.length() <= size) return src;
    int pos = src.lastIndexOf(" ", size - 3);
    if (pos < 0) return src.substring(0, size);
    return src.substring(0, pos) + "...";
}
```

Comment: This is nice and simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for the last occurence of a space that is in a position less or more than 11 and trim the string there, by adding "...".

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements aren't clear.  If you have trouble articulating them in a natural language, it's no surprise that they'll be difficult to translate into a computer language like Java.

"preserve the last word" implies that the algorithm will know what a "word" is, so you'll have to tell it that first.  The split is a way to do it.  A scanner/parser with a grammar is another.

I'd worry about making it work before I concerned myself with efficiency.  Make it work, measure it, then see what you can do about performance.  Everything else is speculation without data.

Comment: Fair enough. What I meant by "preserve the last word" is I do not want to truncate a string on any character except a white space? Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
mystring = mystring.replaceAll("^(.{12}.*?)\b.*$", "$1...");
```

Comment: Can you explain the regex? Would this preserve the last word or not? Your regex is different from Bohemian's.

Comment: Take the first 12 characters, and the minimum after that to complete the word, and add ...

Comment: I actually forgot to add something to the end of the pattern to remove the rest of the string. Editing now to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I use this hack : suppose that the trimmed string must have 120 of length :

```
String textToDisplay = textToTrim.substring(0,(textToTrim.length() > 120) ? 120 : textToTrim.length());

        if (textToDisplay.lastIndexOf(' ') != textToDisplay.length() &&textToDisplay.length()!=textToTrim().length()) {

            textToDisplay = textToDisplay + textToTrim.substring(textToDisplay.length(),textToTrim.indexOf(" ", textToDisplay.length()-1))+ " ...";
        }
```